# Proper rails coding for the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What's the proper way to display a model's attributes in the view if the attributes are not validated with presence. For instance, if the user model has attributes like `website`, `twitter`, `facebook`, and `about`, but these attributes are not required to save the user model.

In the view, there's a chance that the user has a twitter but hasn't provided website. Surely it isn't proper to always use an if statement like:

```
<% if @user.website? %>
  <p><%= @user.website %></p>
<% end %>
```

What's the proper way to show the `<p>` tag with the user's website depending on if the user has a website or not??

Comment: If you are aiming to remove logic from views, you can checkout the Presenter Pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few number ways you can do this, the proper way would really be your preference.  I believe the aim here is readability.  For a simple `p` tag I'd go with the `content_tag` option below.

Some of the options:

Option 1: using [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)

```
<%= content_tag(:p, @user.website) if @user.website %>
```

Option 2: Nesting `p` tag within an `if` block

```
<% if @user.website %>
  <p><%= @user.website %></p>
<% end %>
```